# randomly remove one of the two elements in the list(half the time removing 1 item and half the time removing 2 item)

Tags: java, list

I have a method that will take a List. If the List contains both "item1" and "item2", it should remove one of the
two, but I need to do it random (i.e., half the time removing "item1" and half the time removing "item2"). Otherwise it should leave the List unchanged. If you pass in null, the method should do nothing.

I have a method:

```
public static void removeItem(List<String> items) {
    if (items.contains("item1") && 
            items.contains("item2")) 
{

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomIndex =  random.nextInt(items.size());
        items.remove(randomIndex);

    } else if (items.isEmpty()) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

I am not sure how to make it remove half of the time. Any help appriciated

Comment: Not sure what the issue is?

Comment: If you want a random behavior, you cannot ensure that it will be item1 then item2 half of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shuffling the list can do the trick. 
Though there is no guarantee of `half the time` clause.
You can have any number of items in the list.

May not be a optimal solution, but I can propose this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("item2");
            list.add("item3");
            list.add("item1");
            list.add("item4");

            System.out.println("Before : " + list);
            removeItem(list);
            System.out.println("After : " + list);
        }

        public static void removeItem(List<String> items) {

            if (items == null) {

                // Handle the null list
                System.out.println("List is null");
            } else if (items.contains("item1") && items.contains("item2")) {

                //Shuffle the list, randomize the items and then remove `item1` or `item2` which ever appears earliest.
                Collections.shuffle(items);
// Modern approach
items.stream().filter(i->i.equals("item1") || i.equals("item2")).findAny().ifPresent(i->items.remove(i));
/*
                int removeIndex = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                    if (items.get(i).equals("item1") || items.get(i).equals("item2")) {
                        removeIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                items.remove(removeIndex);
 */   
            } else if (items.isEmpty()) {

            } else {

            }
```

Comment: @jay sedani implementing the logic for half of the time would be a better option

Answer (score 0):

This `checkList` method takes in a `list`, checks if both items are in the list, and removes one of them randomly if they both exist.  Does nothing if the `list` is `null`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("item1");
        list.add("item2");

        list = checkList(list);
    }

    private static List<String> checkList(List<String> list){

        //skip if null
        if(list == null){
            return list;
        }

        //find index of items
        int index1 = list.indexOf("item1");
        int index2 = list.indexOf("item2");

        //if one item doesn't exist in list, its index will be -1
        if(index1 >= 0 && index2 >= 0){

            //get random number between 1 and 2
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

            if(randomNumber == 1){
                //remove item1
                list.remove(index1);
            }else{
                //remove item2
                list.remove(index2);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee one element is removed "half of the time" over the other. What you can do, however, is generate a random number of `0` or `1` and remove one of the elements based on that. This will essentially simulate what you want.

```
public static void removeItem(List<String> items) {
    if (items == null || items.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    if (!items.contains("item1") || !items.contains("item2")) {
        return;
    }

    int randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 2);
    if (randomNumber == 0) {
        items.remove("item1");
    } else {
        items.remove("item2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, randomly remove any item then u can shuffle the items as per the ans of @prashantzombade and if you mean to count the time you are deleting item 1 and item 2 randomly then you can implement the logic of odd even Ni. With static variable.

- make 2 static variables
- get the count of static variables
- implement the logic for half of the time(ex. Avg 50%)
- get random no
- if no. Is even then remove item 2 else item 1
- increase the static variable for even no by 1 if random number is even else variable 2

If you want to implement the following process then comment on ans I will upload the code example.

**Here I am checking exact count of deletion item 1 and item 2(exact half of the time)**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

class hello2
{
    static int evn=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("item1");
        list.add("item2");

        int randomNumber=0;

        //list = checkList(list);
        //skip if null

        if(list!=null){


        //find index of items
        int index1 = list.indexOf("item1");
        int index2 = list.indexOf("item2");

        //if one item doesn't exist in list, its index will be -1
        if(index1 >= 0 && index2 >= 0){

            //get random number between 1 and 2
            Random random = new Random();
            randomNumber = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

            if((randomNumber %2)== 0){
                //remove item1              
                if(evn==1) //if last time item 2 deleted
                {
                    list.remove(index2);                    
                    //System.out.println(list+" Static var="+evn+" Random no: "+randomNumber%2);
                    evn=0;

                }
                //else{System.out.println(list+" Static var="+evn+" Random no: "+randomNumber%2);}
            }else{
                //remove item2
                if(evn==0) //if last time item 1 deleted
                {
                    list.remove(index1);

                    //System.out.println(list+" Static var="+evn+" Random no: "+randomNumber%2);
                    evn=1;                  
                }
                //else{System.out.println(list+" Static var="+evn+" Random no: "+randomNumber%2);}
            }
        }

        System.out.println(list);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: implementing the logic for half of the time would be a better option , I am not sure how to implement code for this detail

Comment: deletion will be ignored if randomly item 2 going to delete more then count of item 1 and same with item 1(vice versa). You can check it with putting this process in a loop.